# Was the d20 SRD ever printed in physical books?

Tags: books, d20-system

I own most of the D&D 3.5e rule books, but I've always wondered: were there any printed books of the d20 SRD ruleset (e.g. like the PHB, DMG, and MM books) that just include the d20 SRD rules, without the non-d20 D&D specific information?

I'd love to have a SRD 3.5 rulebook to keep by my side when gaming or needing to look up information for use in a module or source book that I may wish to write and not have to worry about accidentally including any D&D stuff from their books.

Comment: @Erik I know it seems like it's helpful, but putting little part-answers in comments is counterproductive for the site working well. It's appreciated that users don't get into the habit.

Answer (score 6):

In 2004 during the d20 boom Mongoose published under the Open Gaming License the [*Mongoose Pocket Player's Handbook*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1904577660) and the [*Mongoose Pocket GM's Guide*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1904854508), which, combined, were, essentially, the d20 SRD minus, I think, the monsters. An *RPG.net* review of the former is [here](https://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/9/9993.phtml).